# Android Navigation component: How do not destroy fragmants view switching bottom tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

Im using BottomNavBar with Nav component. Tabs are switching good, but each tab's fragment view is being destroyed every time I leave the tab. I can't catch a logic of this behaviour, because in my case user could go throught tabs fast, and I need to keep each tab fragment in its state (for example a list should be scrolled at certain position etc). Thanks.

Comment: To do this, use Shared preferences. So to say save the last actions of users.

Comment: Fragments already allow you to [save your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) and that includes the scroll position in a list. Does your screen lose its scroll position when you rotate your screen (e.g., go through a config change) or when you enable the "Don't Save activities developer option" and leave/re-enter your activity (e.g., simulate process death/recreation)? If either of those don't work, the problem is with how you are saving state, not with Navigation's behavior. Include your fragment you are having issues with and we can help fix that fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks, but my tab fragments doesn't require  a config change. May be I could be ok with save and restore fragment state every time user click to tabs (why it works so hard?), but why NavController every time puts the fragments to back-stack? So while single session of using the app, back-stack could be 20+ items of just two fragments.

Comment: You have to support config changes - there is no way to opt out of every config change. So again, tell us in what fragment you aren't saving your state correctly and we can help with that actual root issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've tried to use SavedStateHandle for my ViewModel, but: "it do only saves data written to it when the Activity is stopped", so it doen't work for my tab fragments

Comment: Finally I've found partially solution without hacks: used shared ViewModel for parent Activity and a Fragement, so a Fragment do not destroy and I can store its view state there.